# Position of sprite with swift and spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Thanks in advance.
I set a circle in the middle of the screen by using

```
circle = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 100 ) // Size of Circle
    circle.position = CGPointMake(frame.midX, frame.midY)  //Middle of Screen
    circle.strokeColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
    circle.glowWidth = 1.0
    circle.fillColor = SKColor.orangeColor()
    self.addChild(circle)
```

What I'm trying to do is, when the user tap the screen, a sprite will appear from a random position, and move towards the center of the screen. The issue I'm getting is that, sometimes the sprite will appear inside the circle. So my plan is to have the sprite move from out side of the screen towards the center. How can I achieve this?

Here is the code for what I done with the random position

```
let randomX = CGFloat(arc4random()) % self.frame.weith
let randomY = CGFloat(arc4random()) % self.frame.height
```

then set the sprite

```
sprite.position = CGPointMake(randomX, randomY)
```

I tried the following to set the random position of the sprite, none of them are working

```
let randomX = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.width + self.frame.width / 2))) || Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.width - self.frame.width / 2)))
let randomY = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.height + self.frame.height / 2))) || Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.frame.height - self.frame.height / 2)))
```

and

```
let randomX = (CGFloat(arc4random()) % self.frame.width + self.frame.width / 2) || (CGFloat(arc4random()) % self.frame.width - self.frame.width / 2)
let randomY = (CGFloat(arc4random()) % self.frame.height + self.frame.height / 2) || (CGFloat(arc4random()) % self.frame.height - self.frame.height / 2)
```

Comment: calculate the position range in the circle, check if the random position is in the circle, if so do the random calculation again. Until you get the right random value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate a random location in Swift you can use the following:

```
var randomX = CGFloat(Int(arc4random()) % width)
var randomY = CGFloat(Int(arc4random()) % height)
```

Now to generate a random location off of the screen you need to generate locations in 4 possible locations - off the screen to the left, right, top or bottom.

Essentially it is what you were trying to do with your || statement, however that will not work for assigning a non-boolean variable.

Example:

```
func randomPointOffscreen() -> CGPoint
{
    let spawn = arc4random_uniform(4)+1
    var randomX:CGFloat = -100
    var randomY:CGFloat = 100

    switch(spawn)
    {
    case 1:
         randomX =  -CGFloat(Int(arc4random()) % 320)
         randomY = CGFloat(Int(arc4random()) % 640)
        break;
    case 2:
        randomX = 320 + CGFloat(Int(arc4random()) % 320)
        randomY = CGFloat(Int(arc4random()) % 640)
        break;
    case 3:
        randomX = CGFloat(Int(arc4random()) % 320)
        randomY = 640 + CGFloat(Int(arc4random()) % 640)
        break;
    case 4:
        randomX =  CGFloat(Int(arc4random()) % 320)
        randomY = -CGFloat(Int(arc4random()) % 640)
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return CGPointMake(randomX, randomY)
}
```

Comment: I understand the logic behind this and the code you provide, how should I call it thought? currently I'm using: sprite.position = CGPointMake(randomX, randomY)

Comment: I updated the code to be a function that returns a point. Use it to create a random point and set your sprite.position to that point as you mentioned, sprite.position = CGPointMake